# What is "clue" in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is "clue" in Esperanto? I mean, in the sense of a little piece of information, given to help somebody find the anwer to some question, for example a riddle or puzzle. "Hint" might be an English synonym.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I normally say *indiko* and [John Well's dictionary](https://www.smashwords.com/books/view/508176) agrees with this as a translation for ‘clue’. For ‘hint’ it says *aludo* but I think that is translating a different sense of the word.